# Blurry edges in lettering (straight lines)

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to figure out how I can make my letters look better after exporting it to .png format. I'm quite new to it, so any advice is much appreciated.

Its a typographic logo, but the edges are not smooth not only when exported to .png, they are weird even in AI, even thouh they are just straight lines in most cases.

Photos below

AI: https://www.screencast.com/t/3Osvfz5xhZbG
PNG:https://www.screencast.com/t/NmyMAB2j

Can you advise what I can imporve in my pentool technique or generally how can I make it look smoother?

Thanks

Comment: I do not believe this is a technical problem. Your art looks "smooth" in the sense that it doesn't have a blurred or jagged edge - it will be printed with a 100% sharp contour. These "inaccuracies" you don't like comes from the way you have drawn the logo. Maybe you have unnecessary extra points or maybe your handles need tweaking. Maybe it would be easier to help if you post an image where we can see the anchor points and the handles? BTW - it IS hard to make smooth looking vector shapes - it takes a lot of trial and error.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yup I will update this post today with images where handles are visible !

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is change the options in the export to be at a higher ppi for .png and mess with the anti-aliasing settings until you have your desired look.